# Trying to change colour of button using setTimeout function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to change the colour of some buttons in javascript using setTimeout. There seems to be an issue with having more than one style element in the code below?

Any ideas how to fix the code below? Or a better way of getting the counter working?

This is the button style etc:

```
<button type="playball1" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%";onclick = "null">1</button>

function changeButtonColor1() {
    document.getElementById("playball1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function changeButtonColor2() {
    document.getElementById("playball2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function changeButtonColor3() {
    document.getElementById("playball3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function changeButtonColor4() {
    document.getElementById("playball4").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function changeButtonColor5() {
    document.getElementById("playball1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function Playball() {
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor1()',1000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor2()',2000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor3()',3000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor4()',4000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor5()',1000);
};
```

Comment: Your problem is **very** unclear. While you can't have multiple `style` attributes, none of the ones you have would have any effect on your attempts to change the background colour. Your JS refers to elements that don't exist, and has functions that are never called.

Comment: You should provide an [mcve] using the [live demo feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of the question editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because you try to get your element with `getElementById("playball1")` and you've set his type `type="playball1"` instead you should use `id="playball1"`.

I'm not to understand your need but i think you want something like that :

```js
function changeButtonColor(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function playball() {
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor("playball1")',1000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor("playball2")',2000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor("playball3")',3000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor("playball4")',4000);
    setTimeout('changeButtonColor("playball5")',5000);
};
playball();
```

```html
<button id="playball1" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%" onclick="null">1</button>
<button id="playball2" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%" onclick="null">2</button>
<button id="playball3" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%" onclick="null">3</button>
<button id="playball4" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%" onclick="null">4</button>
<button id="playball5" style="border-radius: 12px" style="border-radius: 50%" onclick="null">5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

your functions are not called and also try to manage your code by using one function since they are all doing the same job, check this example

```
 const playball1 = document.getElementById('playball1');
    const playball1 = document.getElementById('playball2');

    let green ='green';
    let red = 'red';
    function changeButtonColor1(element, color) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    changeButtonColor1(playball1,green );
    changeButtonColor1(playball2,red);
```